# Who made or authorized the portkeys used by the order members to gather at the burrow after the battle of the seven Potters?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

I have established in my question [How did the Ministry protect against the use of unauthorized portkeys?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/45919/10926) (at least in my mind) that it is extremely difficult to make and use a portkey **not previously authorized by the Ministry of Magic** (and not get caught).  This is based on the quote, "Its more than our life's worth to set up an unauthorized portkey" stated by Lupin with the entire advanced guard present.

Since that is the case, who on earth made the portkeys that were used after the battle of the seven potters in the final book?  or, if the portkeys were authorized, who gave the okay?

Of course, I am assuming they were trying to keep Harry's movement at least, not obvious, because the Ministry had been infiltrated to some degree by Death Eaters.

Use, or planned use of portkeys listed on pgs. 66 through 69, where it specifies all the "Potters" and their escorts are returning to the burrow through use of Portkeys.

Comment: I disagree entirely with your premise that it's *difficult* to make an unauthorized portkey. I think it's more a case of the legal consequences simply aren't worth the gains.

Comment: I agree with Anthony Grist's comment. There's no indication that it's difficult to make a Portkey; the spell is Portus. In the link I provided in your other question, it is established that coordinating multiple and/or international Portkeys is a PITA, but it seems that's a logistical issue. Portkeys are regulated; one might infer that means an unauthorized person who creates a Portkey could be subject to punishment, but canon doesn't specifically state this. I'm not remembering what Portkeys you're referring to after the battle of the seven Potters and I don't have my book. Could you clarify?

Comment: Honestly, I think the Portkeys used in Deathly Hallows were probably approved by the Ministry. The Burrow, and I think other locations, were protected by the combined might of the Order and the Ministry of Magic, so there was obviously still co-operation between the two even at that late stage.

Comment: @Slytherincess Harry and Hagrid crash landed in the Tonks' garden after the encounter with Voldemort, then took a Portkey to The Burrow. There were another six Portkeys that were supposed to bring the other six "Harrys" and their companions there as well. I assume those are the ones being talked about.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Thanks for clarifying which Portkeys balanced mama was referring to! I would have checked it myself, but my HP books are packed away right now and I can't access them. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: @balancedmama - Oh, no prob! I know how it goes, looking for pages :) Personally, I think your question of "Who authorized the Portkeys?" is a fine one and I don't think it should be closed. It's a legitimate question, IMO.

Comment: IIRC, the point of having seven Potters when leaving Privet Drive was to prevent Voldemort from knowing which particular place Harry was hiding in. If the Ministry knew Harry was ultimately going to the Burrow, and since the Ministry had already been infiltrated, why didn't they know harry would be in the Burrow? I think I've forgotten if this is mentioned.

Comment: @user13267: or if they didn’t know the final destination of the Portkeys, they would at least know that the plan involved multiple Harry’s, which scuppers the element of surprise.

Comment: @alexwlchan: They actually didn't know about the plan involving multiple Harry's. That was the main trick played by Professor Snape. He let them find out the actual date when they were moving harry, but left out the detail that there would be multiple Harry's. He confounded Mundugus and made him tell the order that having multiple Harry's was his (Mundungus') plan. This is explained inside the pensieve, in  Professor Snape's memory

Comment: @user13267: I know, I meant that if the Ministry knew multiple Portkeys were involved (regardless of their final destination was), then they might suspect something was up.

Comment: absolutely! - especially after the fact when Harry was no longer at #4 Privet Dr.  But there was the wedding coming up too so that could be a way to explain it - Bacelorette Party for Fleur or something.

Comment: having multiple portkeys may just be explained as a way to confuse the mole in the Ministry; just have extra portkeys that won't be used to confuse them about which place Harry was going to.

Comment: I don't know why those that could apparate back didn't just simply apparate back personally - much simpler then portkeys only for those still not qualified or with a trace.

Comment: I dont think it is mentioned when the portkeys were created. The order could have had the portkeys to use for an emergency - and probably used it only when they needed to hide Harry. The order member always knew they would need to go into hiding at some point. THis might be one of their precautions. Like the Triwizard cup - the portkeys may be authorized - but the time and destination might've been changed.

Answer (score 1):

On page 12 (chapter 1 - The Dark Lord Ascending) of The Deathly Hallows, Snape is discussing Harry's protection with Lord Voldemort:

> "The place, according to the source, has been given every protection that the Order and Ministry together could provide. I think that there is little chance of taking him once he is there, my lord, unless, of course, the ministry has fallen before next Saturday"

This implies that if the ministry are providing protection on the twelve safe-houses, then surely they would allow portkeys to return to the Burrow (**the** safe-house).

The ministry was indeed infiltrated by death eaters at this point, but Voldemort expresses that they not attempt to take full control until Scrimgeour is surrounded by death-eaters (or imperiused individuals). The ministry are still able to provide protection for the safe houses and keep the details of their enchantments from the death-eaters, which means portkeys should also not be a problem, not until the wedding when the ministry finally falls completely to the death-eaters.

Answer (score 0):

There were members of the "Order of the Phoenix" in the ministry. So someone like Kingsley Shacklebolt shouldn't have to much work arranging some port keys for this event. Also, we know the ministry was involved in Harry's transfer as 1 death eater is telling Voldemort the date they are moving harry which he got from his ministry contacts, while Snape tells the right date to voldemort. So its safe to say they had ministry's approval and that those port keys could have been made and waiting for whenever Harry's move would happen. We know Kingsley was very high in the Auror office so being both in the ministry and part of the "Order of the Phoenix" he was probably in charge of setting up Harry's security, officially anyway.