# Why do staff/students take the Hogwarts Express?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there any particular reason why everyone (or at least most people) use the Hogwarts Express to travel to the school?

It seems as though using portkeys or the flu network would be faster and more direct.

While portkeys can be tampered with (as shown in *Goblet of Fire*), trains could be attacked, have maintenance problems, or be derailed, so they are not infallible either.

Comment: As far as I'm aware Lupin is the only teacher who caught train?

Comment: Can you carry large amounts of luggage through portkeys or the flue network?

Comment: @Liath Professor Slughorn

Comment: @Xantec Yes. One of the Weasley twins travels from Privet Drive to The Burrow via the Floo Network with Harry's trunk in *Goblet of Fire* , and Harry travelled via Portkey with Cedric's corpse (not strictly speaking luggage, but it's a fairly large object).

Comment: Cedric Diggory as luggage ... that's terrible! Just terrible. And I can't stop laughing. Thank you @AnthonyGrist :)) Here's also: [Barring legal issues, why aren't Portkeys used more frequently?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15667/barring-legal-issues-why-arent-portkeys-used-more-often) with links to Pottermore screenshots re: The Hogwarts Express. :)